# Expand elipsis text of single mapped item

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my react app, I am returning data from which contains texts of varying lengths.

```
const ReturnedProducts = () => {

    const textStyle = {
        maxWidth: '100%',
        display: '-webkit-box',
        WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
        WebkitLineClamp: 4,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        marginBottom: '10px',
    };

    //This function returns the correct style to the above div.
    function calculateTextStyle() {
        return truncate ? textStyle : null;
    }
    // Manage if the text should be truncated or not.
    const [truncate, setToggleTruncate] = React.useState(true);

    // Function to toggles the state variable 'truncate', thereby expanding and truncating the text when the user clicks the div.
    function toggleTruncate() {
        setToggleTruncate(!truncate);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AreaWrapper>
                <InnerWrapper>
                    {data.data.products &&
                        products.map(product => (
                            <ProjectCard key={product.id}>
                                <img src={product.image} alt="test" />
                                <ProjectCardTitle
                                    onClick={toggleTruncate}
                                    style={calculateTextStyle()}
                                >
                                    {product.title}
                                </ProjectCardTitle>
                                <ProjectButton>
                                    {product.description}
                                </ProjectButton>
                            </ProjectCard>
                        ))}
                </InnerWrapper>
            </AreaWrapper>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(ReturnedProducts);
```

The expand function works fine, however, when I click a single card on the page, the text expands for all cards. How can I make it so that only the clicked card expands? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are setting truncate to just true/false. u should set it to the product.id

```
  function toggleTruncate(value) {
        setToggleTruncate(value);
    }
```

modify your component to use product.id instead

```
<ProjectCardTitle
       onClick={() => toggleTruncate(product.id)}
       style={ truncate === product.id ? textStyle : null }
>
```